# How can I encrypt a querystring in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt a querystring in ASP.NET.

The querystring might look something like this:

> http://www.mysite.com/report.aspx?id=12345&year=2008

How do I go about encrypting the entire querystring so that it looks something like the following?

> http://www.mysite.com/report.aspx?crypt=asldjfaf32as98df8a

And then, of course, how to I decrypt it? What's the best encryption to use for something like this? TripleDES?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in VB From: http://www.devcity.net/Articles/47/1/encrypt_querystring.aspx

**Wrapper for the encryption code:** Pass your querystring parameters into this, and change the key!!!

```
Private _key as string = "!#$a54?3"
Public Function encryptQueryString(ByVal strQueryString As String) As String
    Dim oES As New ExtractAndSerialize.Encryption64()
    Return oES.Encrypt(strQueryString, _key)
End Function

Public Function decryptQueryString(ByVal strQueryString As String) As String
    Dim oES As New ExtractAndSerialize.Encryption64()
    Return oES.Decrypt(strQueryString, _key)
End Function
```

**Encryption Code:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Encryption64
    Private key() As Byte = {}
    Private IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal stringToDecrypt As String, _
        ByVal sEncryptionKey As String) As String
        Dim inputByteArray(stringToDecrypt.Length) As Byte
         Try
            key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(sEncryptionKey, 8))
            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
            inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), _
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            Return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        Catch e As Exception
            Return e.Message
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal stringToEncrypt As String, _
        ByVal SEncryptionKey As String) As String
        Try
            key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(SEncryptionKey, 8))
            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
            Dim inputByteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( _
                stringToEncrypt)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), _
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        Catch e As Exception
            Return e.Message
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: This almost works. I changed these two lines:
Return Server.UrlEncode(enc64.Encrypt(qs, _key))
and
Return Server.UrlDecode(enc64.Decrypt(qs, _key))
and don't bother with the Replace(" ", "+")

Comment: Also, usage (oh, how i wish i could edit):
Encrypting:
Dim myQS = EncryptQueryString("id=12345&year=2008")
Response.Redirect(String.Format("Default.aspx?q={0}", myQS))
Decrypting:
Dim myQS As String = DecryptQueryString(Request.QueryString("q"))

Comment: is there any other way make encryption but not make url too long ?!
Some times if there is a lot querystrings make the url more than 2000 characters and not good for most browsers

Answer (score 8):

Encryption in C# using AES encryption-

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(txtName.Text.Trim()));
    string technology = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(ddlTechnology.SelectedItem.Value));
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/CS2.aspx?name={0}&technology={1}", name, technology));
}
```

**AES Algorithm Encryption and Decryption functions**

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "hyddhrii%2moi43Hd5%%";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}


private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "hyddhrii%2moi43Hd5%%";
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

**To Decrypt**

```
lblName.Text = Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["name"]));
lblTechnology.Text = Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["technology"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a turn key solution off the top of my head, but you should avoid TripleDES since it is [not as secure as other encryption methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES).

If I were doing it, I'd just take the entire URL (domain and querystring) as a [URI object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), encrypt it with one of the [built-in .NET libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx) and supply it as the `crypt` object. When I need to decrypt it, do so, then create a new URI object, which will let you get everything back out of the original querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of fancy version of the decrypt function from Brian's example above that you could use if you were only going to use this for the QueryString as it returns a NameValueCollection instead of a string. It also contains a slight correction as Brian's example will break without

```
stringToDecrypt = stringToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+")
```

if there are any 'space' characters in the string to decrypt:

```
Public Shared Function DecryptQueryString(ByVal stringToDecrypt As String, ByVal encryptionKey As String) As Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
    Dim inputByteArray(stringToDecrypt.Length) As Byte
    Try
        Dim key() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey.Substring(0, encryptionKey.Length))
        Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
        Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
        stringToDecrypt = stringToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+")
        inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
        cs.FlushFinalBlock()
        Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        Dim decryptedString As String = encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        Dim nameVals() As String = decryptedString.Split(CChar("&"))
        Dim queryString As New Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(nameVals.Length)
        For Each nameValPair As String In nameVals
            Dim pair() As String = nameValPair.Split(CChar("="))
            queryString.Add(pair(0), pair(1))
        Next
        Return queryString

    Catch e As Exception
        Throw New Exception(e.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

I hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

I was originally going to agree with Joseph Bui on the grounds that it would be more processor efficient to use the POST method instead, web standards dictate that if the request is not changing data on the server, the GET method should be used.

It will be much more code to encrypt the data than to just use POST.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to encrypt your query string? If the data is sensitive, you should be using SSL. If you are worried about someone looking over the user's shoulder, use form POST instead of GET.

I think it is pretty likely that there is a better solution for your fundamental problem than encrypting the query string.

Comment: We are using SSL as well, but someone decided to just pass this data on the querystring a long time ago, so that's the way it will be for now.

Comment: If you are already using SSL, you only care about shoulder surfing, so how about using Convert.ToBase64String(data) and Convert.FromBase64String(base64) on the parameter values.